# Scheduling a Spark Job Java

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I have a Spark job which reads an HBase table, some aggregations and store data to mongoDB. Currently this job is running manually using the spark-submit script. I want to schedule it to run for a fixed interval.

How can I achieve this using java.

Any library? 
Or Can I do this with Thread in java?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: to schedule jobs you can use cron

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to still use `spark-submit` I would rather prefer **crontab** or something similar and run bash script for example.

But if you need to run "spark-submit" from java you can take a look to [Package org.apache.spark.launcher](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/launcher/package-summary.html). With this approach you can start application programatically with `SparkLauncher`.

```
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkAppHandle;
import org.apache.spark.launcher.SparkLauncher;

...

     public void startApacheSparkApplication(){
        SparkAppHandle handler = new SparkLauncher()
         .setAppResource("pathToYourSparkApp.jar")
         .setMainClass("your.package.main.Class")
         .setMaster("local")
         .setConf(...)
         .startApplication(); // <-- and start spark job app
     }
...
```

But your question was about some scheduling library. You can use a simple `Timer` with `Date` provided in java util (`java.util.TimerTask`), but I would prefer to use [Quartz Job Scheduling Library](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org) - it is really popular (As I know spring [uses Quartz Scheduler too](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)).

> Spring also features integration classes for supporting scheduling
>   with the Timer, part of the JDK since 1.3, and the Quartz Scheduler (
>   http://quartz-scheduler.org)
>   ....
>
> With Quartz you can set cron scheduling and for me it is more easier
>   to work with quartz.

Just add maven dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.quartz-scheduler/quartz -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
    <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.3</version>
</dependency>
```

create spark - Quartz job

```
   public class SparkLauncherQuartzJob implements Job {
         startApacheSparkApplication();
   ...
```

now create a trigger and schedule it

```
 // trigger runs every hour
 Trigger trigger = new Trigger() 
             .withIdentity("sparkJob1Trigger", "sparkJobsGroup")
             .withSchedule(
                 CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0 * * * * ?"))
             .build();


  JobDetail sparkQuartzJob = JobBuilder.newJob(SparkLauncherQuartzJob.class).withIdentity("SparkLauncherQuartzJob", "sparkJobsGroup").build();

  Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
  scheduler.start();
  scheduler.scheduleJob(sparkQuartzJob , trigger);
```

***Unlikely*** - If you have spring boot application you can use scheduling for running some methods very easy - just `@EnableScheduling` in configuration and something like this:

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 300000)
public void periodicalRunningSparkJob() {
    log.info("Spark job periodically execution");
    startApacheSparkApplication();
}
```