# Spark RDD filter right after spark streaming

Tags: java, apache-spark, bigdata, spark-streaming, hazelcast

I am using spark streaming and I read streams from Kafka. After reading this stream, I am adding it to hazelcast map.

The issue is, I need to filter values from map right after reading stream from Kafka.

I am using below code to parallelize map values.

```
List<MyCompObj> list = CacheManager.getInstance().getMyMap().values().stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
JavaRDD<MyCompObj> myObjRDD = sparkContext.parallelize(list);
```

But in this logic, I am using JavaRDD in another one which is JavaInputDStream.foreachRDD and this causes serialization issues.

First question is, how can I run my spark job by event driven?

On the other hand, I just want to get some opinion about scheduled spark jobs. 
what is the best practice to schedule a spark job to execute it in specific time(s)?

Comment: It seems there is no connection between your first problem descriptions and your last two questions. am I right?

Comment: I am afraid, not for first one. During streaming, I need to run filter on all values of map. the first question is related with this. Streaming running over an RDD and I need to run filter over another RDD which depends on this streaming event.    But you absolutely right for second question. I just want to get some opinion. Let me edit my question. Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issues by separating streaming and batch processing in two parts as it must be.

I am using quartz and SparkLauncher to trigger a new job  ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869446/scheduling-a-spark-job-java))

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [Hazelcast Jet](https://jet.hazelcast.org/)? It's a streaming engine built by Hazelcast. Continuously pumping the data from Kafka to Hazelcast a fault tolerant way is it's bread and butter, see the [code sample](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples/blob/master/kafka/src/main/java/KafkaSource.java#L72)

Jet is packaged with embedded Hazelcast which simplifies the architecture for you.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I read a bit for hazelcast jet but I need to work on spark a bit more.